# Handling file in mongodb with gridfs

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

Handeling file in mongodb with gridfs

I have the questions below which i try to find the answer more than a week and can't find anything interesting as answer in the net:

1) is it possible to insert via gridfs 2 differents files in the same mongofile request into mongo database? Can the files have the same and `uniq files_id`

2) I have user collection and each user have one or many files uploded into mongodb. Is it possible to make a link between users and file? I would like to know which file belongs to each user.

3) So is it possible to have file's metadata (fs.files by default) in the user collection. For exemple something which will look like:

```
{  
   _id:112,
   Firstname:“Mickael”,
   Lasttname:“Jackson”,
   Files:[  
      {  
         _id:5910e57f24f3f7047494720c 
         "filename":"File1",
         "chunkSize":NumberInt(261120),
         "uploadDate":ISODate("2014-04-13T11:32:33.557Z"),
         "md5":"7b762939321e146569b07f72c62cca4f",
         "length":NumberInt(646)
      },
      {  
         _id:1841e57f24f3f7047494720b 
         "filename":"File2",
         "chunkSize":NumberInt(261120),
         "uploadDate":ISODate("2014-04-13T11:32:33.557Z"),
         "md5":"7b762939321e146569b07f72c62cca4f",
         "length":NumberInt(646)
      }
   ]
}
```

Thank's in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Is it possible to insert via gridfs 2 differents files in the same mongofile request into mongo database? Can the files have the same and unique files_id.

   Even if this was possible, I don't recommend this. You should do one request per file.
   No they cannot have same unique _id. If you need secondary id use metadata property of fs.file
2. I have user collection and each user have one or many files uploded into mongodb. Is it possible to make a link between users and file? I would like to know which file belongs to each user.

   Yes you can create link between users and documents in fs.files collection.
   To do this you can use DBRefs, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs. Where you store reference of the fs.files documents in user.files
   Basically, you can have a user structure like this,

   ```
   {  
       _id:112,
       Firstname:“Mickael”,
       Lasttname:“Jackson”,
       Files:[  //YOU WILL ONLY STORE _id of fs.files
            {
               "$ref" : "fs.files",
               "$id" : ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab772"),//file of id
               "$db" : <database name>
            }
       ]
   }
   ```

   Or you can even have metadata property in the fs.files and assign the user id there.

   ```
   {
        _id:1841e57f24f3f7047494720b 
        "filename":"File2",
        "chunkSize":NumberInt(261120),
        "uploadDate":ISODate("2014-04-13T11:32:33.557Z"),
        "md5":"7b762939321e146569b07f72c62cca4f",
        "length":NumberInt(646)
        "metadata" :{
               user : {
                   "$ref" : "users",
                     "$id" : 112,
                     "$db" : <database name>
               }
   }
   ```

   Note that there is no SQL like constraint, 
   if you delete the user, you have to also delete files that belongs to that user. 
   Otherwise there will be orphans.
3. So is it possible to have file's metadata (fs.files by default) in the user collection.

I don't think this is possible. As fs.files has to be a collection of its own.
Also, in terms of design this separation is better.

Comment: Hi Samip,  thank you for you contribution. It's now more clear for me. I will use the first approch  by modifying the users collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
{  
   _id:112,
   Firstname:“Mickael”,
   Lasttname:“Jackson”,
   Files:[  
      {  
         _id:5910e57f24f3f7047494720c 
         "filename":"File1",
         "chunkSize":NumberInt(261120),
         "uploadDate":ISODate("2014-04-13T11:32:33.557Z"),
         "md5":"7b762939321e146569b07f72c62cca4f",
         "length":NumberInt(646)
      },
      {  
         _id:1841e57f24f3f7047494720b 
         "filename":"File2",
         "chunkSize":NumberInt(261120),
         "uploadDate":ISODate("2014-04-13T11:32:33.557Z"),
         "md5":"7b762939321e146569b07f72c62cca4f",
         "length":NumberInt(646)
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is your formatted code

Comment: Nice to hear you